# How to use zero matches in regular expression?

Tags: regular-expression, search

I have following text

```
_printer
_printer
_printer
_printer
_printer
_printer
_printer
_printer
printer
```

and I want to find the last one by using a search for the text `printer` which is not preceded by an underscore character `_`.

I know that zero matches are `!`: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/zero-width

so I tried:

```
/!_printer
/!/_printer
/!\_printer
/![_]printer
/(_)@!printer
/_@!printer
//_@!printer
/\_@!printer
```

None of them works. What is the correct pattern for this search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong zero width multi item. `\@!` is negative look-*ahead*. You could use it to e.g. find any `printer` that is not *followed* by an underscore:

```
/printer_\@!
```

The multi item you want to use is negative look-*behind* `\_@<!`:

```
/_\@<!printer
```

See `:help \_@<!`

An alternative technique would be to use:

```
/\_[^_]printer/s+1
```

Find any character (including an end-of-line) that is *not* an underscore, followed by `printer`, and place the cursor one character on from the beginning of the match.

Comment: And I believe one could use `/\_[^_]\zsprinter` as an alternative to the `/s+1` form.